# NumPy: is assignment of a scalar to a slice broadcasting?

Tags: python, numpy

I know in Python,

```
[1,2,3][0:2]=7
```

doesn't work because the right side must be an iterable.

However, the same thing works for NumPy ndarrays:

```
a=np.array([1,2,3])
a[0:2]=9
a
```

Is this the same mechanism as broadcasting? On https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html, it is said broadcasting is only for arithmetic operations.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html - broadcasting is used in multidimensional index as well as with indexed assignment.  Your link says it is used in arithmetic operations - but does not use **only**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assignment follows the same rules of broadcasting because you can also assign an array to another array's items. This however requires that the second array's shape to be broadcastable to destination slice/array shape.

This is also mentioned in [Assigning values to indexed arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays) documentation:

> As mentioned, one can select a subset of an array to assign to using a single index, slices, and index and mask arrays. The value being assigned to the indexed array must be shape consistent (the same shape or broadcastable to the shape the index produces).